# Prometheus requires that all meters with the same name have the same set of tag keys

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus, spring-micrometer

If @Around only @Timed annotated method like this:

package ru.fabit.visor.config.aop;

```
import io.micrometer.core.annotation.Timed;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Tag;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Tags;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Timer;
import io.micrometer.core.lang.NonNullApi;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.StreamListener;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.function.Function;

/**
 * The type Targeted timed aspect.
 */
@Aspect
@NonNullApi
public class TargetedTimedAspect {

    public static final String DEFAULT_METRIC_NAME = "method.timed";

    public static final String EXCEPTION_TAG = "exception";
    public static final String BINDING_TAG = "binding";
    public static final String SCHEDULED_CRON_TAG = "cron";

    private final MeterRegistry registry;
    private final Function<ProceedingJoinPoint, Iterable<Tag>> tagsBasedOnJoinPoint;

    public TargetedTimedAspect(MeterRegistry registry) {
        this(registry, pjp ->
            Tags.of("class", pjp.getStaticPart().getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(),
                "method", pjp.getStaticPart().getSignature().getName())
        );
    }

    public TargetedTimedAspect(MeterRegistry registry, Function<ProceedingJoinPoint, Iterable<Tag>> tagsBasedOnJoinPoint) {
        this.registry = registry;
        this.tagsBasedOnJoinPoint = tagsBasedOnJoinPoint;
    }

    // enable TimedAspect only for @StreamListener and @Scheduled annotated methods or allowed methods pointcut
    @Around("timedAnnotatedPointcut() )")
    public Object timedMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        Method method = ((MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature()).getMethod();

        StreamListener streamListener = method.getAnnotation(StreamListener.class);
        Scheduled scheduled = method.getAnnotation(Scheduled.class);
        // timed can be on method or class
        Timed timed = method.getAnnotation(Timed.class);
        if (timed == null) {
            method = pjp.getTarget().getClass().getMethod(method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes());
            timed = method.getAnnotation(Timed.class);
        }

        final String metricName = timed.value().isEmpty() ? DEFAULT_METRIC_NAME : timed.value();
        Timer.Sample sample = Timer.start(registry);
        String exceptionClass = "none";

        try {
            return pjp.proceed();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            exceptionClass = ex.getClass().getSimpleName();
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            try {
                Timer.Builder timerBuilder = Timer.builder(metricName)
                    .description(timed.description().isEmpty() ? null : timed.description())
                    .tags(timed.extraTags())
                    .tags(EXCEPTION_TAG, exceptionClass)
                    .tags(tagsBasedOnJoinPoint.apply(pjp))
                    .publishPercentileHistogram(timed.histogram())
                    .publishPercentiles(timed.percentiles().length == 0 ? null : timed.percentiles());

                if (streamListener != null) {
                    timerBuilder.tags(
                        BINDING_TAG,
                        streamListener.value().isEmpty() ? streamListener.target() : streamListener.value()
                    );
                } else if (scheduled != null) {
                    timerBuilder.tags(SCHEDULED_CRON_TAG, scheduled.cron());
                }

                sample.stop(timerBuilder.register(registry));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // ignoring on purpose
            }
        }
    }

    @Pointcut(
        "(@annotation(org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.StreamListener) ||" +
        "@annotation(org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled))"
    )
    public void asyncAnnotatedPointcut() {
        // Method is empty as this is just a Pointcut, the implementations are in the advices.
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(public * ru.fabit.visor.service.impl.StorageClientImpl.*(..)) ||" +
        "execution(public * ru.fabit.visor.service.s3storage.S3StorageClientImpl.*(..))")
    public void allowedMethodPointcut() {
         // Method is empty as this is just a Pointcut, the implementations are in the advices.
    }

    @Pointcut("@annotation(io.micrometer.core.annotation.Timed)")
    public void timedAnnotatedPointcut() {
        // Method is empty as this is just a Pointcut, the implementations are in the advices.
    }

}
```

Then return: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Prometheus requires that all meters with the same name have the same set of tag keys. There is already an existing meter named 'web_photos_gotten_list_seconds' containing tag keys [class, exception, method]. The meter you are attempting to register has keys [exception, method, outcome, status, uri].

But, if add all @Timed method in Pointcut, all good work, i dont understand, why we need all annotated method add to Pointcut separately?

This work:

```
    package ru.fabit.visor.config.aop;

import io.micrometer.core.annotation.Timed;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Tag;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Tags;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Timer;
import io.micrometer.core.lang.NonNullApi;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.StreamListener;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.function.Function;

/**
 * The type Targeted timed aspect.
 */
@Aspect
@NonNullApi
public class TargetedTimedAspect {

    public static final String DEFAULT_METRIC_NAME = "method.timed";

    public static final String EXCEPTION_TAG = "exception";
    public static final String BINDING_TAG = "binding";
    public static final String SCHEDULED_CRON_TAG = "cron";

    private final MeterRegistry registry;
    private final Function<ProceedingJoinPoint, Iterable<Tag>> tagsBasedOnJoinPoint;

    public TargetedTimedAspect(MeterRegistry registry) {
        this(registry, pjp ->
            Tags.of("class", pjp.getStaticPart().getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(),
                "method", pjp.getStaticPart().getSignature().getName())
        );
    }

    public TargetedTimedAspect(MeterRegistry registry, Function<ProceedingJoinPoint, Iterable<Tag>> tagsBasedOnJoinPoint) {
        this.registry = registry;
        this.tagsBasedOnJoinPoint = tagsBasedOnJoinPoint;
    }

    // enable TimedAspect only for @StreamListener and @Scheduled annotated methods or allowed methods pointcut
    @Around("timedAnnotatedPointcut() && (asyncAnnotatedPointcut() || allowedMethodPointcut())")
    public Object timedMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        Method method = ((MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature()).getMethod();

        StreamListener streamListener = method.getAnnotation(StreamListener.class);
        Scheduled scheduled = method.getAnnotation(Scheduled.class);
        // timed can be on method or class
        Timed timed = method.getAnnotation(Timed.class);
        if (timed == null) {
            method = pjp.getTarget().getClass().getMethod(method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes());
            timed = method.getAnnotation(Timed.class);
        }

        final String metricName = timed.value().isEmpty() ? DEFAULT_METRIC_NAME : timed.value();
        Timer.Sample sample = Timer.start(registry);
        String exceptionClass = "none";

        try {
            return pjp.proceed();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            exceptionClass = ex.getClass().getSimpleName();
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            try {
                Timer.Builder timerBuilder = Timer.builder(metricName)
                    .description(timed.description().isEmpty() ? null : timed.description())
                    .tags(timed.extraTags())
                    .tags(EXCEPTION_TAG, exceptionClass)
                    .tags(tagsBasedOnJoinPoint.apply(pjp))
                    .publishPercentileHistogram(timed.histogram())
                    .publishPercentiles(timed.percentiles().length == 0 ? null : timed.percentiles());

                if (streamListener != null) {
                    timerBuilder.tags(
                        BINDING_TAG,
                        streamListener.value().isEmpty() ? streamListener.target() : streamListener.value()
                    );
                } else if (scheduled != null) {
                    timerBuilder.tags(SCHEDULED_CRON_TAG, scheduled.cron());
                }

                sample.stop(timerBuilder.register(registry));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // ignoring on purpose
            }
        }
    }

    @Pointcut(
        "(@annotation(org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.StreamListener) ||" +
        "@annotation(org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled))"
    )
    public void asyncAnnotatedPointcut() {
        // Method is empty as this is just a Pointcut, the implementations are in the advices.
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(public * ru.fabit.visor.service.impl.StorageClientImpl.*(..)) ||" +
        "execution(public * ru.fabit.visor.service.s3storage.S3StorageClientImpl.*(..))")
    public void allowedMethodPointcut() {
         // Method is empty as this is just a Pointcut, the implementations are in the advices.
    }

    @Pointcut("@annotation(io.micrometer.core.annotation.Timed)")
    public void timedAnnotatedPointcut() {
        // Method is empty as this is just a Pointcut, the implementations are in the advices.
    }

}
```

pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Are you using also `io.micrometer.core.aop.TimedAspect`? And if not, why not?

Comment: if also add TimedAspect, will be the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem youre discribing has nothing to do with pointcuts. There is one piece of code that generates a Timer with three tags (`class`, `exception`, `method`) and another one creating the timer with the exact same same with 5 tags (`exception`, `method`, `outcome`, `status`, `uri`) and the framework clearly says, that this is now allowed.

There are several possibilites to solve the issue:

- simply use another name for the timer (if you need the other one)
- find the other piece of code that generates that timer and deactivate it. Maybe you need to use the debugger and set an conditional breakpoint in MeterRegistry.register()` that registers the meters with the condition that the meter name matches.

PS: using the URI as a tag is not a good practice. The issue is that anyone access your service using different URIs (e.g. by just adding a random number) that will end up in a very high number of meters, which will finally kill your prometheus.